# Is there more better cancel nested ManyToMany field unique check

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
# models.py

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField( max_length=256)
    student_numer = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

# serializers.py

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name', 'student_number', )


class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students = StudentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        students = validated_data.pop('students')

        # here I want delete all old students, and add all new students
        # of course, I have more better way to update it, but here just for simple.
```

But in fact, if I update teacher instance, and if the students not change, it will
raise: student with this student_numer already exist.
I know why, because StudentSerializer's student_numer field has the validator check unique.
And I can add some code like this to fixed this problem:

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name', 'student_number', )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'student_numer': {
                'validators':[]
            }
        }
```

Now I want to know is there any more better way ??

Comment: would you mind adding your current code for update?

Comment: i still use these way,(or just write the student_number with char field in serializer, and remove from fields ) but i think this studentSerializer should only use for this situation. if only want to operate student, should write new one, i think most case unique check is useful. and i think this design is not problem, modelserializer just for create instance or update it.